# How to take Input As Table and Submit in Mysql Table

Tags: php, html, forms

I am Trying to make a Result Management System where I take the Students names from Mysql Database and Each have a Unique Id. I want to Render it as a Table Where There Were Be Rows And Columns.
I have Also Done but How can I use $_POST and Save it in the Mysqli as there are 100 + Values.
The thing I done is :

```
        php

   while ($student_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res){
        <input type = "number" name = "mark1-<?php echo $student_row['roll']">
        }
```

I have Done And Now I get All values by $_POST but it is difficult to define every variable and then submit it to the MySql Table.

If I can Do With Any Library then Please Tell.

Like the Image Given :
[image: Like This Image I want to Make]

Comment: You should not try to mimic an excel spreadshseet on a web interface! Have a form where you can edit only one student's various grades and marks and another form where you can select which student to edit.

Comment: @Shadow I m Not Mimicing An Excel What Can I do If I want to Save an Excel Directly on Db From User Input ?

Comment: That's a very different question - let's focus at the one at hand :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help, even if the question is not really clear (for me), but if you write your input name this way:

```
<input name="students[id_of_the_student][ppt]"/>
<input name="students[id_of_the_student][ma]"/> 
<input name="students[id_of_the_student][nb]"/>...
```

You'll have this in your post var:

```
var_dump($_POST["students"]);
/*
array(1) { // quantity of students in table
  [id_of_student]=> array(2)//number of inputs
  {
    [ppt] = "PPT value",
    [ma] => "MA value"
  }
}
*/
```

Edit: This is how your table/form should look like:

```
<form id="form-students" method="POST" >
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>PPT</th>
            <th>MA</th>
            <th>MB</th>
            <!-- And so on... -->
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php while($student_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <?php foreach ($student_row as $key => $value) : ?>
                        <td><input type="text" name="students[<?= $student_row['id'] ?>][<?= $key ?>]" value="<?= $value ?>"></td>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </tr>
            <?php endwhile;?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>

<?php 
$students = $_POST['students'];
?>
```

Comment: Means I want to Submit that All Values To Database

Comment: Please see the Edited Question

Comment: I think this structure still helps you. Create the table inside a form, then get the whole student data by their id in the `$_POST['students']` variable

Comment: Take a look now